# How to remove an css style from a div ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, replace

I am using [`jQuery Autosize`](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize) to enable automatic height for textarea elements.

When I focus the textarea it works great.
If I blur the texture I would like to remove the `height` to the texture to resize the height to the default value.

I would like to know what should I do `on blur` action in order to keep the textarea to the default value.

Here is what I am trying to do on javascript console to test my script.

When I load the page the textarea is on blur state:

```
$('#announcement').css('height'); // "36px"
```

If I focus the textarea:

```
$('#announcement').css('height'); // "90px"

$('#announcement').removeAttr('height');
$('#announcement').css('height'); // "90px" 
// why do I continue to get this value even if I removed the Attribute height?
```

I know I can simply fix my problem simply making on blur action
`$('#announcement').css('height', '36px');`
but I would like o avoid to set css properties in javascript code.
Any ideas?

Comment: height is not an attribute...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clear the `style.height` set directly on the element with this:

```
$('#announcement').css('height', '');
```

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/LXspR/

In your example, `removeAttr()` works on attributes, not style properties like `style.height`.  `.css("height")` works on `style.height`.